# Remote notification format by html text - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

I received a notification alert as a html format. So how can I display that notification message format by html using custom user notification. Any help would be appreciated.

example:

```
aps : {
    alert : "<a>this is a tag</a><br/><b>this text will bold out</b>",
}
```

Comment: You can not display html formatted text in iOS as there is no rich text support in iOS Push Notification.

Comment: If your you want to show custom alert with UILabel on your app, check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/35008239/3485139

But if you question is how show this message on notification center without tags, my answer no way

Comment: thanks so much guys!

Comment: Also it´s not a good practise that the api send styling informations to the mobile device. The mobile device should check the category or action parameter and format the informations itself